# Why doesn't Stack Overflow have a humans.txt?

Tags: discussion

The Stack Exchange team are very transparent and open. Have they considered adding a [humans.txt](http://humanstxt.org/) to the Stack Exchange websites?

Comment: `"...contains information about the different people who have contributed to building the website."`. That's every single one of us ;) Would be a big file...

Comment: I guess the question is actually _"Why implement it?"_ This is your feature request so you should be providing reasons for implementing the request. "Google is doing it" isn't really a reason...

Comment: I present: [Stack Overflow's humans.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/users).

Comment: You guys are posting answers as comments again!

Comment: @Lix Well, to be honest, I don't think _all_ users in there are human (and, no, I don't just mean [community](http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community))

Comment: For some reason I keep seeing an implied equivalence between robots.txt and humans.text, but I just don't see what it could be. One is a set of instructions to cooperating webcrawlers, the other is a bunch of credits.

Comment: @Yannis Does not compute.....

Comment: @Bart He is right.  Some of us are not humans.

Comment: While I appreciate the spirit of the humans.txt campaign, I think its actually a terrible idea security-wise since it gives a potential attacker ammo in a social engineering attack, letting them know exactly which individuals within a company to target to potentially gain access to the resources they control. Not saying this should be a concern for SO, just in general, esp. smaller companies w just 1 or 2 employees run the whole show

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's not called `humans.txt`, but they do have an about page.   Use the 'Management' and 'Team' tabs on [that page](https://stackoverflow.com/about) to reach https://stackexchange.com/about/team, where the full team is listed.

There are also "Welcome Stack Overflow Valued Associate #000X blog posts for most of the team, available by [searching for that phrase](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=partner-pub-6254779591266030%3Awa6mxc6y8y6&ie=ISO-8859-1&q=Welcome+Stack+Overflow+Valued+Associate&sa=Search#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=Welcome%20Stack%20Overflow%20Valued%20Associate&gsc.page=1) or filtering the [announcements category](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/announcement/) on the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/).

humanstxt.org states:

> Because it's something simple and fast to create. Because it's not intrusive with the code. More often than not, the owners of the site don't like the authors signing it; they claim that doing so may make the site less efficient.

In this case, Jeff and Joel take time to blog about each employee, and give them a face on a set of pages specially designed to show off the team.  This is, IMO, better than a humans.txt, and 'about' is linked in the top of every page rather than being hidden behind a secret URL.

I might support redirecting humans.txt to the /about/team page, but the current setup is better.

Answer (score 7):

They kinda do, https://stackexchange.com/about/team.

Comment: d'oh, I forgot that I'm supposed to post quickly and then edit within the 5-minute window.  FGITW goes to you on this one!

Comment: @Kevin From experience, quality can easily trump speed. Lose not yer faith!

Answer (score 5):

[From the Wikipedia entry about humans.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humans.txt):

> There are no standards to the file. Developers are free to include
>   whatever content they wish. The primary goal is to acknowledge
>   contributors to a site.

We already have something like that, it's the `/users` page. There you can see who contributed to the site in quite some detail. I see no advantage in putting that information into an unformatted and unstandardized text file.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any payoff for implementing this. It would basically reproduce our existing user list unless you propose some sort of criteria where users would be featured in that file.

If you needed to do something *exceptional* and difficult to game like modem whistling an answer to the server that gets 100 up votes in order to get your name in that file along with [geek code](http://www.geekcode.com/), I can see it becoming a source of nerdish pride unlike any gold badge we've seen.

Implementing it just for the *sake* of implementing it seems like a bit of a waste to me.

Answer (score 3):

"All the cool kids are doing it" seems to be the only argument for doing this, really. As pointed out before, an organised list of contributors to the site already exists, so a humans.txt would be redundant.