# Add humans.txt to stackoverflow.com

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t Stack Overflow have a humans.txt?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111794/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-have-a-humans-txt)

http://humanstxt.org/

/humans.txt is a "human equivalent" to /robots.txt

I just found it today, and it seems companies like [Google](http://www.google.com/humans.txt) and [Github](https://github.com/humans.txt) are implementing it.

Why not implement is on SO as well?